# Where can I find more information on this mysterious IC? (V100 ZJ51VMP)

Tags: identification

I'm trying to identify this logo/part, I've searched combinations of the letters that appear on it as well as IC manufacturer logos and didn't have much luck.  At one point I was pointed to a "display processor" site but I can't seem to find it again.  Here is the image:

[image: whatsthis]

There is a USB port with the power pins running to this chip.  I supplied 3.3V with my programmable power supply, it appears its is drawing about 300 mA.  The display turns on, displays a lightning bolt graphic/animation, as if the battery is charging, and that's it.

Other info: A rather unique device was turned into lost and found and no one has claimed it, so it was turned over to the hardware lab to properly dispose of it--but I'm curious, what is it?!  It is a device that has a lithium ion battery, some push buttons, a small speaker, a panel display (HYB070HD), and a 2Gb NXP RAM component. None of it is in an enclosure, rather its a circuit board glued to the back of the display with the push buttons dangling by wires soldered t other.

Comment: It's a mailed video advertisement. I have one here that was programmed with a commercial for a projector company, and another that was programmed with several videos advertising a security camera company. I generally dismantle these kits and use the perfectly good components for other projects.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to change the video/ access the storage on the chip @Centium

Comment: Another variant, received March 2022. This one is driving a fairly nice little 4" 16:9 LCD panel. Mounted inside a cardboard sleeve. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUBUC.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a V100 chip from chinese IC company [Actions Semiconductor](http://www.actions-semi.com/en/products.aspx).

The chip function is described in [this](https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/actions-semiconductor-launches-the-v100-chipset-for-personal-3d-cinema-headsets-300313216.html) press release:

> The V100 is a versatile, all-in-one solution tailored for 3D movie
>   watching applications. The V100 integrates a MIPS32 processor together
>   with a compact integrated video engine, display subsystem and audio
>   engine to deliver an immersive 3D video experience. It supports up to
>   1280x800@60fps LCD display and all standard video decoding playback
>   capabilities which includes H.264 FHD 1080P@30fps video decoder. The
>   V100 features DDR2/DDR1 DRAM, SPI NOR, NAND Flash Controller with max
>   40-bit ECC, integrated RGB and LVDS LCD interface, built-in stereo
>   20-bit DAC and 20mW power amplifier for headphones. The V100 offers
>   rich interfaces such as USB 2.0, SDIO and integrates several
>   regulators to maximize power efficiency and reduce residual heat.